# Anyone know where to get raw telemetry data for JWT / Webb telescope

Tags: nasa, james-webb-telescope

https://webb.nasa.gov/content/webbLaunch/whereIsWebb.html has a nice graphical representation of the JWT / Webb Telescope as far as distance traveleled, distance to go,  current temperature, etc.  I'd like to get this data in a text / json / csv format. Does anyone know where that data is available in a text based format?

Comment: Text format is unlikely, as it depends on what your reference frame is.  The community uses SPICE to track spacecraft: https://repos.cosmos.esa.int/socci/projects/SPICE_KERNELS/repos/jwst/browse